# where can I read the source code?

Tags: smalltalk, squeak

I am using squeak4.1 for development, when I am looking up add method in  method chain below: Kernel-Numbers -> Integer -> arithmetic -> + ,the method for adding is +, in + method I find 
sample code like this :

```
ifTrue: [^ (self digitAdd: t1) normalize].
```

Can I know how I can trace into digitAdd and look the implementation of add method in smalltalk? thanks first!

Comment: Select the message and press Cmd or Alt + m

Answer (score 1):

As the message is send to `self`, you can query the `Integer` class itself for its definition.  For this, right click `Integer` in the System Browser, select "find method" and enter `digitAdd' in the search window that appears. Click the "Accept" button. This will show you the message definition.

You can also use the search facility in Squeak. (the search box on the main menu bar).

Answer (score 1):

Select string 'digitAdd:' in text editor, and press Alt-m shortcut or right-click and in opened menu find 'implementors of it'.
This will open a window with all methods in all classes in system which implement given message.